# How to set grid space in plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, grid

I want to add a grid on my plot. Unofrtunetely, I found only Grid normal and Grid miror,
I want to add a grid that appear every 5 value on y-axis, This is my code:

```
function DisplayNumber(x,y1,y2,Name,Method)
plot(x,y1,'-s','MarkerSize',9,...
    'MarkerEdgeColor','green',...
    'MarkerFaceColor',[0 0.4470 0.7410])
hold on 
legend({'cos(x)','cos(2x)','cos(3x)','cos(4x)'},...
    'Location','northwest','NumColumns',2)
p=plot(x,y2,'-s','MarkerSize',9,...
    'MarkerEdgeColor','yellow',...
    'MarkerFaceColor',[0.6350 0.0780 0.1840])
hold off 
xtickangle(0)
max(y1);
Max= max( max(y1),max(y2));
ylim([0 Max+10]);
Max=max(x);
xlim([1 Max+1]);
legend( strcat(Method,"-AHP"),strcat(Method,"-MOWOA-NIS"));
ylabel('Rank reversal ratio %');
xlabel('Number of networks');
xticks(0 : 20)
grid on
set(gcf,'Units','Inches');
pos = get(gcf,'Position');
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','Auto','PaperUnits','Inches','PaperSize',[pos(3), pos(4)])
print(gcf,Name,'-dpdf','-r0')
end
```

I tried `yticks(0:5:Max+10)` but it did not work.

Comment: The grid lines are placed where the ticks are. So using `xticks` and `yticks` is the way to go. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: What are the typical min and max values in your `y1` and `y2`. If your values range from 0.0 to 0.1 a spacing of `5` is not adequate. Same goes if your `y` values range from 0 to 65356.